# multiple checkboxlists using repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

The following is my code to show One Title followed by one `checkboxlist`.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repRoles" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:literal runat="server" text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemTitle") %>></asp:literal>
              <br />
              <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" DataSourceID=<%# FillinCbl(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemID").ToString()) %> 
                                    DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ItemValue">
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
private void FillinRepeater()
{
    try
    {
        List<Item> targetAudienceParent = new List<Item>();
        DataTable tempTbl = new DataTable();
        tempTbl.Columns.Add("ItemTitle", typeof(String));
        tempTbl.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(String));
        DataRow tempRow;
        int tempCount = 0;
        foreach (Item a in itmECM.Children)
        {
            try
            {
                tempRow = tempTbl.NewRow();
                tempRow["ItemTitle"] = a.Name.ToString();
                tempRow["ItemID"] = a.ID.ToString();
                tempTbl.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                tempCount++;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        repRoles.DataSource = tempTbl;
        repRoles.DataBind();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
public DataTable FillinCbl(String passedString)
{
    dtlRoles = new DataTable();
    dtlRoles.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
    dtlRoles.Columns.Add("OptInID", typeof(String));
    dtlRoles.Columns.Add("OptOutID", typeof(String));
    Item tempItm = master.GetItem(passedString);
    DataTable tempTbl = new DataTable();
    tempTbl.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(String));
    tempTbl.Columns.Add("ItemValue", typeof(String));
    DataRow tempRow;
    try
    {
        populateUsersList(tempItm);
        Session["dtlRoles"] = dtlRoles;
        for (int a = 0; a < dtlRoles.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Write(dtlRoles.Rows[a][0].ToString().Trim() + "<br/>");
                tempRow = tempTbl.NewRow();
                tempRow["ItemName"] = dtlRoles.Rows[a][0].ToString().Trim();
                tempRow["ItemValue"] = dtlRoles.Rows[a][1].ToString().Trim();
                tempTbl.Rows.Add(tempRow);
            }
            catch(Exception ex1)
            {
                Response.Write(ex1.ToString() + "<br/>");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        Response.Write(ex2.ToString() + "<br/>");
    }
    return tempTbl;
}
```

The problem is only the literal is showing. The `checkboxlist` is not filled in.

When I `response.write()` for my `DataBind` method for `checobxlist` they are out.

So my code behind is working. There is something missing though. But I can't find out what.

Comment: Kind of. I have tested that the `DataSource` method is calling `FillInCbl` and the `DataTable` is filled with the values. It is just not binding to the `checkboxlist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change DataSourceID to DataSource

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataSource=<%# FillinCbl(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ItemID").ToString()) %>  DataTextField="ItemName" DataValueField="ItemValue">
```